# Can I make my code not accept any input other than an int C#

Tags: c#

I'm wanting my code to just accept an integer. I thought by putting an if else statement with the int ranges would help with this however when text is entered as in input it just crashes the program. How can I fix this.

```
using System;

namespace planetage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double mercuryYears = 0.24;
          
            

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age"); //Ask for users age
            int userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //take users age and convert to int from string

            if (userAge >= 0 && userAge <= 150) {

                double mercuryAge = userAge / mercuryYears; //calculation for age on mercury
                Console.WriteLine("Your age on Mercury is " + mercuryAge); //output age on mercury
            
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(someString, out var someInteger)) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_) for `Convert.ToInt32(string)`, you will see that an exception is thrown under the following condition:

> `FormatException`
> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

If you want to continually ask for a valid integer until one is given, you could use the following approach:

```
int userAge;
do Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age");
while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userAge) is false);

// Do something with userAge..
```

[`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) returns `true` only if the `string` has successfully been converted to an `int`, and does not throw any exception.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age"); //Ask for users age
            int userAge;
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userAge)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number");
            }
            if (userAge >= 0 && userAge <= 150)
            {

                double mercuryAge = userAge / mercuryYears; //calculation for age on mercury
                Console.WriteLine("Your age on Mercury is " + mercuryAge); //output age on mercury

            }
```